# Removable Singularities for a exponential type function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having difficulty with the following problem:

Let $ f:C-A \to C$ be analytic where A is discrete and for all $a \in A$, a is a simple pole with $Res_{a}f$ a positive integer. Define $ F: C-A \to C$ by $F(z) = \exp(\int_{\gamma_{b}{z}}f(w)dw$) where $\gamma_{b}{z}$ is some contour in $C-A$ from b to z (where b remains fixed for all such contours). Show F has removable singularities at each $a \in A$.

Showing this F is well-defined and analytic on $C-A$ is straightforward, but I am not sure how to get any sort of bound on a punctured disk about $a \in A$.

Comment: Maybe there is a printing error on what I was looking at? If that were the definition then if ${z_{0}, z$ were connected by a straight line $L_{z_{0}{z}$ in a punctured disk about a, then f would have have a primitive in a simply connected collar of the line and using additivity of the integral $F(z) = F(z_{0})exp(-(f(z) - f(z_{0})) = F(z_{0})exp(f(z_{0}))exp(-f(z))$ which approaches 0 as z approaches a since f(z) approaches infinity as z approaches a?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of proving a bound, it is easier to directly establish an extension of $F$ into the points of $A$:

Let $a \in A$ and $r > 0$ so small that $D_{r}(a) \cap A = \{a\}$. Pick a $c \in D_r(a)\setminus \{a\}$.

Then we have

$$F(z) = F(c)\cdot \exp \left(\int_{\gamma_{c z}} f(w)\,dw\right)$$

for $z \in D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$, where $\gamma_{c z}$ is a path in $D_r(a)\setminus \{a\}$ connecting $c$ and $z$. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ be the residue of $f$ in $a$, and decompose

$$f(z) = \frac{k}{z-a} + g(z),$$

where $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (A\setminus\{a\})$. Then

$$h(z) = \int_c^z g(w)\,dw,$$

where the integral is over any piecewise continuously differentiable path in $D_r(a)$ connecting $c$ and $z$, is holomorphic on $D_r(a)$, and independent of the choice of path. Hence $H(z) = e^{h(z)}$ is a well-defined holomorphic function on $D_r(a)$.

Further, for the integral over the principal part of $f$ in $a$, we have

$$\lambda(z) = k\cdot\int_{\gamma_{c z}} \frac{dw}{w-a} = k\cdot \left(\log \frac{z-a}{c-a} + 2m\pi i\right),$$

where $m$ depends on the choice of the branch of the logarithm and the path (how often it completely winds around $a$). Note that $\lambda$ is not a well-defined function (it becomes one if the choice of path and branch are determined), so writing $\lambda(z)$ is an abuse of language.

However,

$$\Lambda(z) = e^{\lambda(z)}$$

is a well-defined function on $D_r(a)\setminus \{a\}$, since the possible values of $\lambda(z)$ differ by multiples of $2\pi i$, and we see that

$$\Lambda(z) = \frac{(z-a)^k}{(c-a)^k}$$

has a removable singularity [which becomes a zero of order $k$ after being removed] in $a$.

Hence

$$F(z) = F(c)\cdot H(z)\cdot \frac{(z-a)^k}{(c-a)^k}$$

also has a removable singularity in $a$.